# Android: TelephonyManager class

Tags: java, android

I don't understand why in the API documentation it is written that `TelephonyManager` class is `public`, but when I try to make an instance it says it is not a public class and not accessible out of the package.

I see that it also says to use `Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` to get a reference to an instance to it, but I just don't get it how come a public class cannot be instantiated.
Can someone explain?

Comment: TelephonyManager is a public class but its constructor is hidden..so you can not create TelephonyManager object directly!!!

Comment: TelephonyManager manager=Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); wil give you a instance of telephonymanager.

Comment: @Chandrakanth what is mean by "constructor is hidden"? Do you mean it is declared as "private"?

Comment: Hidden means the constructor has the @hide annotation. hide is used for things that need to be visible for various reasons but are not part of the published API.

Comment: @Chandrakanth: Agree. However, hide attribute is just part of javadoc(droiddoc also), so the "hide" annotation  just simply mean the method/class/field is excluded from the API docs. So How come this annotation is preventing "TelephonyManager " object creation?