# Java APK Non-Static usage

Tags: java, android

i am trying to follow this answer for the same issue from here [Android: TelephonyManager class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019259/android-telephonymanager-class), however when I do as Advised I get an unable to use getSystem service in a static context. How do I do this in a non-static context

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    @TargetApi(26)

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        TelephonyManager device = Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String IMEI = device.getImei();
```

i thought i could do

```
TelephonyManager device = new TelephonyManager(Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
```

but that didnt work, and I still had 'unable to use getSystemService in a static context error'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does "didn-t work mean"? compile error? runtime error? what is the exact errormessage?

Comment: sorry, shall edit, i got the same error as i did without the change.

Comment: what type of exception causes your app to stop ? post your log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your linked question, `TelephonyManager`'s constructor is hidden. This is because the entire phone shares one `TelephonyManager` (as one would expect -- how could there be more than one app using the phone at a time?). To retrieve the `TelephonyManager`, you need to request it from your application's `Context`.

```
TelephonyManager device = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried using the above, and although the code now copiles, when trying to run it on the phone, it immediately just says my application has stopped. If i un-comment that line, it works fine, so something in that request is still causing issues.

Comment: Check your LogCat. My guess is that it's a security exception. Does your app properly request permissions to access the TelephonyManager?

Comment: I have added in the manifest the READ_PHONE_STATE permission as that is what the android doc says I require, are there further permissions I need for telephonymanager.

I haven't heard of LogCat. Is this a tool I need to download for my phone? (I am a newbie dev and this is my first project I am working on using android sdk)

Comment: [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) is where all the output of Android programs go when attached for USB debugging. If your program is throwing an exception, it will show up there. If you're using Android Studio, it should be the first tab under Android Monitor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. figured out this issue due to your guidance.

i needed to add

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE); to request the permission within the app, and not just declare it in the manifest.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Android started requiring runtime permission requests starting with version 23, I believe.